# Starting a local instance of Mosquitto

Tags: macos, mosquitto

I am starting to learn about MQTT, and at the moment I am trying to setup a local instance on my laptop. 
This afternoon I installed mosquito on my mac using `brew install mosquitto`.

After the install finished I tried running `mosquito` but nothing initiated.

Is there a set of steps out there to start up a local instance? I have looked at the steps on [http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-8.html] but I do not understand them.

I'm just trying to figure out step by step how I initiate this thing.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045974/restarting-the-mosquito-broker), you could do:

```
$ launchctl load /usr/local/Cellar/mosquitto/1.4.2/homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto.plist
$ launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto
```