# Restarting the mosquito broker

Tags: macos, sockets, mqtt, mosquitto

I have installed mosquito broker on my mac using `brew install mosquitto`.

Normally I don't give any commands to start the mosquitto server. It is started automatically when I switch on my mac.

I have verified that it is running by using the command `ps -ef | grep mosquitto`, which gives the following output

```
501   209   153   0  2:20PM ??       0:06.93/usr/local/opt/mosquitto/sbin/mosquitto -c /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
501  2559  1007   0 10:36AM ttys001    0:00.00 grep mosquitto    
501   865   815   0  2:32PM ttys003    0:00.86 mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -t esb.test2
```

Then I stopped the server by killing the mosquitto process using `kill -9 above-pid`.

Now I would like to know how can I restart the server again from command line,  but without restarting my mac.

Comment: This is a much clearer question, thank you. The sense of the question has changed substantially since my answer though, which makes it look very odd. If you are going to substantially change a question it is better practice to delete the question and create a new one.

Answer (score 10):

If you've installed mosquitto from homebrew, you can use launchctl to control the service, e.g.

```
$ launchctl load /usr/local/Cellar/mosquitto/1.4.2/homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto.plist

$ launchctl unload /usr/local/Cellar/mosquitto/1.4.2/homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto.plist

$ launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto
$ launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto
```

Comment: can you please add more info for each launchctl command you have mentioned or please provide a link to related resources. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could kill the mosquitto process using the steps detailed in the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/192219/is-there-a-way-to-list-and-kill-running-processes-on-mac-os-x-in-a-windows-ctrl), then restart it in the same way you did originally.

To summarise the answer

```
killall mosquitto
```

Should do the job to stop the existing process.

Comment: What i need is not to kill the port . To start that killed broker/server again without restarting  mac.

Comment: In the terminal just type "mosquitto" then, or /path/to/mosquitto , or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: It will be useful to list the steps you follow to:
1) start mosquitto in the first place
2) stop/kill mosquitto
3) start it again
This will allow us to know the exact problem you are facing